# Pattern for setting an upvalue for DiscreteShift

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, design-patterns

I'd like to set an upvalue for DiscreteShift that changes the rules for being raised to a power:

```
Unprotect[DiscreteShift];
DiscreteShift /: Power[DiscreteShift[f_, i_], r_] := DiscreteShift[f, {i, r}];
Protect[DiscreteShift];
Power[DiscreteShift[f[n], n], 2] === DiscreteShift[f[n], {n, 2}]
```

But I'm getting these error messages:

```
Rule::rhs: "Pattern i_ appears on the right-hand side of rule i_->1+i_. "
TagSetDelayed::tagnf: "Tag DiscreteShift not found in (1+Pattern[f_,_])^r_."
```

It doesn't seem to like the pattern for DiscreteShift's arguments, but I can't get anything else to work there, either. What is the correct way to write this?

**Edit:**
I'll try to clarify my goal. Here's what I want to do mathematically:

```
(N + n) f(n) = N f(n) + n f(n)
             = f(n+1) + n f(n)

(N + n)^2 f(n) = (N^2 + Nn + nN + n^2) f(n)
               = N^2 f(n) + Nn f(n) + nN f(n) + n^2 f(n)
               = f(n+2) + (n+1) f(n+1) + n f(n+1) + n^2 f(n)
               = f(n+2) + (2n+1) f(n+1) + n^2 f(n)
```

So I have this funny N operator that acts as a discrete shift, and we're sort of overloading the meaning of multiplying to have it operate on a function. I had hoped to represent `N f(n)` by using `DiscreteShift[f[n],n]`, and then fixing the power rule for it.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656

Comment: I believe your updated question will take some time to address correctly, time I don't have right now.  I shall revisit it later, if it is not already answered by then.

Comment: Patrick, I am sorry, I did not come back to this.  I shall to spend some time on it very soon.  I am surprised nobody answered your update already.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I appreciate all of your help, but don't feel pressured to get back to it.

Comment: @Patrick, I am finally looking at this again.  This looks like a polynomial expansion, but I would expect `(N + n)^2 f(n)` to yield `n^2 f(n) + 2 n f(n+1) + f(n+2)`.  Please tell me why this is not so.  Sorry for not understanding your example; maybe it will "click" in a few minutes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's because the `N` doesn't commute normally with `n`. So after multiplying out (in the second line), you have a `Nn f(n)` term and a `nN f(n)` term. The `N` affects any function of `n` to its right, so `Nn = n+1`. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think I understand.  Interesting.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `DiscreteShift[f[n], n]` in `Power[DiscreteShift[f[n], n], 2]` evaluates to `f[1 + n]` before anything else happens.  This effects both your attempt at creating a rule, and the actual execution of `Power[DiscreteShift[f[n], n], 2]`.

Compare to your result:

```
Unprotect[DiscreteShift];
DiscreteShift /: Power[HoldPattern[DiscreteShift[f_, i_]], r_] := 
  DiscreteShift[f, {i, r}];

Power[Unevaluated@DiscreteShift[f[n], n], 2] === DiscreteShift[f[n], {n, 2}]
```

```
(* Out[] = True *)
```

---

belisarious gave [a link to a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198961/what-is-in-your-mathematica-tool-bag/5149656#5149656) by which you may intercept evaluation of a built-in function to insert your own code.  However, I think it would be difficult to combine this with `TagSet` to DiscreteShift.

Comment: +1. The problem is, most people would not like to use `Unevaluated` all the time, and to my knowledge there is no robust way to do this without it (not to detract from your answer). I discussed extensively  exactly this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408310/unwanted-evaluation-in-assignments-in-mathematica-why-it-happens-and-how-to-de/7409957#7409957

Comment: Leonid I wanted to link to that answer, but I could not find it in time.  Thank you!

Comment: I will have to take more time to study the links posted, but it seems to me that DiscreteShift's evaluation first is desirable. I want things like f[n+1]^2 to evaluate to f[n+2].

Comment: @Patrick, if you want `f[n+1]^2` to evaluate to `f[n+2]` then `DiscreteShift` is out of the picture and you will need to attach a rule to either `Power` or better `f`.

Comment: I originally wanted to solve this using a downvalue on `Power`, but this rule should only apply to symbols with a specific head, so I thought the head might as well be `DiscreteShift`. Is it possible that I can still do this, but use `Hold@DiscreteShift` (or some variant of `Hold`) instead?

Comment: @Patrick a simple replacement of `HoldPattern` and `Unevaluated` with `Hold` will fail, because the nesting is too deep.  Also, it is normally inadvisable to overload a symbol as basic as `Power`. If you would be willing to describe your application in further detail, I may have a suitable suggestion (you can make it an edit to your question, if you find that appropriate).

Comment: @Patrick, is it acceptable to use alternate operators such as `CirclePlus` and `CircleTimes`?